# multiple apache ports for mediawiki 1.27.0

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, mediawiki

I've been running Mediawiki for quite a few years. My server operates two ports: port `80` for the active site and port `81` for the test site, used when upgrading the MW software before 'going live'. I've not had any issues with this setup until recently. Both ports have worked fine, including an early test of MW 1.27 Alpha on port 81. Now that I'm trying to install MW 1.27.0 (Stable) I'm having issues.

For some reason I can only get http served on one port. If I restart Apache either port will deliver content, but only that port and it's always the first port I visit. The other will then give some PHP error. For example: Restart Apache and go to the site on port 81. Works fine, but the port `80` site gives a PHP error. Change nothing, but restart Apache again and go to the port 80 site; works fine, but port 81 site now gives a PHP error. Either site gives a different PHP error, but always the same error.

This is obviously something to do with my Apache setup, but I have no idea what. It's worked in the past and has not changed. There have been no changes/updates to the OS or Apache application files. Ports are defined in `apache2/ports.conf` with both sites defined in separate `VirtualHosts` conf files.

Both sites are enabled and the config files have been read by Apache (`/usr/sbin/apache2 -S`).

`netstat -lep --tcp` shows that port `80` and `81` are being actively listened to, but both these facts are somewhat irrelevant as I have proved that both ports are able to serve, just not at the same time. I've checked the apache error log file, but there is only the PHP error recorded in there.

I should add that the server has a third site running off another port (8083), which works just fine. All three configs are comparable, differing only in any specified paths (such as `DocumentRoot`) and port number.

Anyone have any suggestions?

**Code:**

**ports.conf:**

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:81
Listen 0.0.0.0:8083
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**wiki.conf:**
NB: ServerAdmin variable has been altered for business/security reasons.

```
#Variable to store the top level server name
Define TL_ServerName lgsim

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    # ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin abc@myDomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wiki

    ServerName ${TL_ServerName}
#   ServerName 44.80.10.2
    ServerAlias ${TL_ServerName}
    DirectoryIndex index.php lgsim_redirect.html

    Alias /w /var/www/wiki
    Alias /wiki /var/www/wiki/index.php
    Alias /error_html/ /var/www/html/error_html/
    Alias /addSearch/ /var/www/html/addSearch/

    <Directory "/var/www/wiki">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # For security, deny access to the MW config directory.
    # Comment this out if you're running an upgrade.
    <Directory "/var/www/wiki/mw-config">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/wiki/images">
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    ErrorDocument 404 /error_html/custom404.html

    #ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    #CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# Template for the virtual host alias currently in use
<Macro VHost $name $redirectURL>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/wiki"
    ServerName $name

    Redirect permanent / $redirectURL
</VirtualHost>
</Macro>

#
#Landing Gear Virtual Hosts
#
Use VHost LG http://${TL_ServerName}/wiki/LG:Main_Page
Use VHost LGSIM http://${TL_ServerName}/wiki/LGSIM:Main_Page
Use VHost LGMS http://${TL_ServerName}/wiki/LGMS:Main_Page

UndefMacro VHost
```

**newWiki.conf:**

```
#Variable to store the top level server name
Define TL_ServerName lgsim

<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerAdmin abc@myDomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wiki_test

#   ServerName 44.80.10.2
    ServerName ${TL_ServerName}
    ServerAlias ${TL_ServerName}
    DirectoryIndex index.php # lgsim_redirect.html

    Alias /w /var/www/wiki_test
    Alias /wiki /var/www/wiki_test/index.php
    Alias /error_html/ /var/www/html/error_html/
    Alias /addSearch/ /var/www/html/addSearch/

    <Directory "/var/www/wiki_test">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # For security, deny access to the MW config directory.
    # Comment this out if you're running an upgrade.
#   <Directory "/var/www/wiki_test/mw-config">
#       Order allow,deny
#       Deny from all
#   </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/wiki_test/images">
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    ErrorDocument 404 /error_html/custom404.html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wiki_test_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wiki_test_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What php error is displayed? Maybe you should also paste your VirtualHosts configuration :)

Comment: I'll add the PHP errors later because it involves kicking the site offline. Generally they're complaining about undefined variables, but the code clearly works when apache is 'happy' serving a port as described above.

Comment: When the main site is working the php error is: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Wikimedia\\Assert\\Assert' not found in /var/www/wiki_test/includes/Services/ServiceContainer.php on line 139

Comment: As a sanity check I've done some simple checks. With the main wiki site operational I've created some simple HTML and PHP pages on port 21. These have worked fine, but I still get the above error message in the logs when I try to access mediawiki PHP on port 21. I stress again that the mediawiki code works *IF* I navigate to that port first after restarting apache, but then the other port errors.

Comment: that should read port 81 in the previous comment!